# Visual Studio: How to select different Python environment depending on build configuration

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm building a `Python` wrapper for my `C++` code in Visual Studio 2017.

For testing a build in 32-bit (x86), I would like to use the 32-bit Python environment, and for a build in 64-bit, I would like to use the 64-bit Python environment.

Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way to do this, except manually activating the corresponding Python environment. This is not saved on a build configuration level.

Any idea how to do this?

[image: Select a Python environment depending on the build configuration]

Regards,

Ben